# A bijection between between the orbits $G$ on $G \backslash B \times G \backslash B$ and orbits of $B$ on $G \backslash B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $B$ a subgroup. Can somebody show me how that orbits of $G$ on $G \backslash B \times G \backslash B$ are in bijection with the orbit of $B$ on $G \backslash B$?

Here is what I've come up with so far:

Let $(aB,cB) \in G \backslash B \times G \backslash B$.

Then $G.(aB,cB) = \{(gaB,gcB) : g \in G\}$

By setting $ga = h$ we can see that this is in bijection with:

$=\{(hB,ha^{-1}cB) : h \in G\}$

Now, if we have $(hB,ha^{-1}cB) = (h'B,h'a^{-1}cB)$ then $(h'^{-1}hB,h'^{-1}ha^{-1}cB)=(B,a^{-1}cB)$ and in particular $h'^{1}h \in B$. I felt like this might be going in the write direction to showing the desired bijection.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Even better, we can say $$ \frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K} \cong \bigsqcup_{HgK}\frac{G}{H\cap {}^gK} $$ are equivalent $G$-sets for any subgroups $H,K\le G$ (the disjoint union is taken over double cosets $HgK$, and ${}^gK:=gKg^{-1}$). See if you can show this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two step hint:

**step 1**

show that every orbit of $G$ on $G/B\times G/B$ contains an element of the form $(B,gB)$.

**step 2**

Consider $\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$. What is the subgroup of $G$ that fixes this? Notice that orbits of $G$ are in bijection with the orbits of this stabiliser and up to a few explanatory words, you're there.

Comment: $(hB,hgB) = (B,gB) \rightarrow b \in B$ and $g^{-1}hg \in B$. So the stabilizer will be $N_G(B)$.

Comment: If you could help me finish the proof that'd be great haha. Why are the orbits of $G$ in bijections with the orbits of this stabilizer?

Comment: Your first comment seems to have a typo - should be $h\in B$. I actually meant the *setwise* stabiliser of $\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$, so you don't require $hgB=B$, you only need $h\in B$. So the subgroup in question is $B$.


Now, consider an orbit $\Delta$ of $G$. If $(B,gB),(B,hB)\in\Delta$ then there is some $x\in G$ with $xB=B$ and $xgB=xhB$ - in particular $x\in B$. This tells us that $\Delta\cap\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$ is an orbit of $B$.


This gives you your bijection between orbits.

Comment: Did you mean that I don't require $hgB = gB$? Thanks for all this by the way!!

Comment: I did, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused... Wouldn't $hgB = gB$ still be required when calculating the setwise stabiliser? What kind of other stabiliser is there anyway?

Comment: The setwise stabiliser of $\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$ is the set those $h\in G$ such, for all $g\in G$, we have $(hB,gB)=(B,xB)$ for some $x\in G$. That is, $h$ fixes the set $\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$, but does not necessarily fix each $(B,gB)$. The set of $h$ which fix all $(B,gB)$ is called the *pointwise* stabiliser of $\{(B,gB):g\in G\}$ and is contained in the setwise stabiliser.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you for your patience. And again, you meant to say $(hB,hgB) = (B,xB)$.

Comment: Again, I did, thank you!